# App Data on Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a **Xamarin.Forms** Android app where an image source is set via a URL which changes from time to time.

When the URL is changed, the old image is still shown.

When I go to *Clear App Data* for my app in system settings, the new image appears.

Is there anyway way to stop the image being preserved in App data?

I'm not doing any explicit caching in my code unless there is some caching built in.

Comment: can you confirm that your code doesn't store the data in local and you are using the local database ?

Comment: I can confirm this. I literally have an image declared in XAML and I'm setting its source property to a URL via C#.